# Merging specific x axis labels using ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis-labels

I am using ggarrange to make a combined plot, showing how different spatial distributions of white matter hyperintensity volume ("WMH") predict general cognitive function. For each spatial distribution of WMH, I show both the overall plot of the whole sample with a single trendline, and then replicate the same plot but with separate trendlines for each group included in the sample. I do this four times, so in total I end up with eight plots (see attached figure). [How the current figure looks with eight plots, each row shows the same WMH distribution predicting ACE-III score, just displayed in a different way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T6lD.jpg)

I am wondering if there is a way to merge the labels for each row, so for example, the first two graphs along the top row (row A), there would be a single centred axis label of "Total WMH +1 (mm3)" instead of two "Total WMH +1 (mm3)" labels, with this repeating for the other WMH volume distributions. I was able to do this with "ACE-III Scores" because it is the same dependent variable in all instances, unlike each WMH volume distribution.

Here is my code:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
#> Installing package into 'C:/Users/camhe/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2'
#> (as 'lib' is unspecified)
#> package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
#> 
#> The downloaded binary packages are in
#>  C:\Users\camhe\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgZbHG6\downloaded_packages
install.packages("ggpubr")
#> Installing package into 'C:/Users/camhe/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2'
#> (as 'lib' is unspecified)
#> package 'ggpubr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
#> 
#> The downloaded binary packages are in
#>  C:\Users\camhe\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgZbHG6\downloaded_packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


#For Total WMH +1 (mm3)
tWMH_ACE_plot_whole <- ggplot(newsubj_twmh_megattracks_and_honours_dropna, aes(tWMH_1, ACE)) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5, alpha = 0.5, aes(col=Classification)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", colour = "black", level = 0.95, alpha = 0.25) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Total WMH + 1 (mm3)") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))

tWMH_ACE_plot_bygroup <- ggplot(newsubj_twmh_megattracks_and_honours_dropna, aes(tWMH_1, ACE, col=Classification)) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se = F) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Total WMH + 1 (mm3)") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))


#For Juxtaventricular WMH +1 (mm3)
jWMH_ACE_plot_whole <- ggplot(newsubj_twmh_megattracks_and_honours_dropna, aes(jWMH_1, ACE)) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5, alpha = 0.5, aes(col=Classification)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", colour = "black", level = 0.95, alpha = 0.25) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Juxtaventricular WMH + 1 (mm3)") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))

jWMH_ACE_plot_bygroup <- ggplot(newsubj_twmh_megattracks_and_honours_dropna, aes(jWMH_1, ACE, col=Classification)) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se = F) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Juxtaventricular WMH + 1 (mm3)") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))


#For Periventricular WMH +1 (mm3)
pWMH_ACE_plot_whole <- ggplot(newsubj_twmh_megattracks_and_honours_dropna, aes(pWMH_1, ACE)) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5, alpha = 0.5, aes(col=Classification)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", colour = "black", level = 0.95, alpha = 0.25) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Periventricular WMH + 1 (mm3)") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))

pWMH_ACE_plot_bygroup <- ggplot(newsubj_twmh_megattracks_and_honours_dropna, aes(pWMH_1, ACE, col=Classification)) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se = F) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Periventricular WMH + 1 (mm3)") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))


#For Deep WMH +1 (mm3)
dWMH_ACE_plot_whole <- ggplot(newsubj_twmh_megattracks_and_honours_dropna, aes(dWMH_1, ACE)) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5, alpha = 0.5, aes(col=Classification)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", colour = "black", level = 0.95, alpha = 0.25) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Deep WMH + 1 (mm3)") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))

dWMH_ACE_plot_bygroup <- ggplot(newsubj_twmh_megattracks_and_honours_dropna, aes(dWMH_1, ACE, col=Classification)) + 
  geom_point(size=2.5) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se = F) + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Deep WMH + 1 (mm3)") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14), legend.title = element_text(size = 16), axis.title = element_text(size = 14), axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))


#Combining all these graphs into one
all_ACE_combined <- ggarrange(
  tWMH_ACE_plot_whole, tWMH_ACE_plot_bygroup, jWMH_ACE_plot_whole, 
  jWMH_ACE_plot_bygroup, pWMH_ACE_plot_whole, pWMH_ACE_plot_bygroup, 
  dWMH_ACE_plot_whole, dWMH_ACE_plot_bygroup, nrow = 4, ncol = 2, 
  common.legend = T, legend = "right",
  labels=c("A", "", "B", "", "C", "", "D", ""))

all_ACE_combined <- annotate_figure(all_ACE_combined,
                left = text_grob("ACE-III Scores", size = 14, rot = 90))
```

I tried using annotate_figure in a similar way to how I created the ACE-III scores y-axis label, but shortly realised afterwards that it was not going to be an appropriate solution as not only are each of these WMH Volumes unable to be summarised under one x-axis label, but I also need the placement of these labels to be placed in the centre of each row, underneath the respective graphs whereas I think annotate_figure works only in terms of coarse directions ("left", "right", "top", "bottom").

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Eventually (not yet) one might be able to use `patchwork`, where combining axes is on the roadmap ([patchwork#150](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/150)).

Comment: Are all of your `x=` aesthetics from the same domain? That is, are `tWMH_1`, `jWMH_1`, `pWMH_1`, and `dWMH_1` all in the same numeric range of values?

Comment: @r2evans they are!

Comment: Have you tried using facets instead of ggarrange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done with faceting instead of `ggarrange`. This does require "exploding" (expanding the data by as many models as you have), but I don't think it'll be an issue.

I'll explain by walking through a similar dataset (3 `y` values) from simple to faceted-one-model to faceted-multiple-models.

Data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y1 = runif(10), y2 = runif(10), y3 = runif(10))
dat
#     x     y1     y2      y3
# 1   1 0.9148 0.4577 0.90403
# 2   2 0.9371 0.7191 0.13871
# 3   3 0.2861 0.9347 0.98889
# 4   4 0.8304 0.2554 0.94667
# 5   5 0.6417 0.4623 0.08244
# 6   6 0.5191 0.9400 0.51421
# 7   7 0.7366 0.9782 0.39020
# 8   8 0.1347 0.1175 0.90574
# 9   9 0.6570 0.4750 0.44697
# 10 10 0.7051 0.5603 0.83600
```

For all examples below, I'm using `tidyr::pivot_longer`, though it can trivially be adapted to `reshape2::melt` or `data.table::melt` depending on your preferences.

## Simple

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x)
```

[image: ggplot, single variable]

(Notice that the formula is still `y ~ x` regardless of the actual column names applied to the `aes`thetics.)

## Multiple `y` variables, one smoothing models

```r
pivot_longer(dat, -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x) +
  facet_grid(~ name)
```

[image: ggplot, three variables one model, faceted]

Notice that we now have all three variables (my `y1`, `y2`, and `y3`, projecting to your `tWMH_1`, `jWMH_1`, and `pWMH_1`) with one smoothing model.

In your case, I suggest `select`ing only the x/y variables you need and removing any other variables; if you don't, either `pivot_longer` will complain about different classes (if not all `numeric`), or they will appear as apparent `y` variables (which is not the plot you're intending to create).

I should note that the default behavior with `facet_grid` is that the `x` and `y` axes will be the same across all panes; this can be relaxed using `scales="free"` (or `"free_x"` or `"free_y"`), but one purpose of this question (I believe) is to normalize the axes, so we'll keep them scaled to the same range.

## Multiple `y` variables, multiple models

For this, we will need to repeat each data for each model. The actual names of the models are used in the facet strips/labels, so make them whatever you want. (`crossing` is also from `tidyr`, same as `pivot_longer`. There are non-dplyr methods for this as well, if needed.)

```r
print(crossing(dat, model = c("loess", "lm 95%", "lm 99%")), n = 5)
# # A tibble: 30 × 5
#       x    y1    y2    y3 model 
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1     1 0.915 0.458 0.904 lm 95%
# 2     1 0.915 0.458 0.904 lm 99%
# 3     1 0.915 0.458 0.904 loess 
# 4     2 0.937 0.719 0.139 lm 95%
# 5     2 0.937 0.719 0.139 lm 99%
# # … with 25 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Now we're going to pivot (changing from `-x` to `-c(x, model)`), and update the faceting. For each type of model, we're going to subset the data that ggplot is using internally, so that each `geom_smooth` is only used on the `model` value we want it to; we use a `~`-style (rlang) data argument so that it dynamically subsets the current data.

(I use `dplyr::filter` below; if you are not using `dplyr`, you can replace it perfectly with `subset`.)

```r
crossing(dat, model = c("loess", "lm 95%", "lm 99%")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(x, model)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data = ~ filter(., model == "loess"),
              method = "loess", formula = y ~ x) +
  geom_smooth(data = ~ filter(., model == "lm 99%"),
              method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, level = 0.99) +
  geom_smooth(data = ~ filter(., model == "lm 95%"),
              method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, level = 0.95) +
  facet_grid(model ~ name)
```

[image: ggplot, multiple y variables, multiple smoothing methods, faceted]

## Wrapup

In this faceting example, I have 3x3; in yours, you have 4 variables and 2 smoothing methods to show for each. As an alternative to `facet_grid(..)`, you can instead use `facet_wrap(~ name + model, nrow = 2)`. The order of `~ name + model` changes how the facet strips are structured. There are extension packages for ggplot2 that offer slightly nuanced ways to vary this faceting, such as @teunbrand's `ggh4x` and its [nested facets](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#nested-facets).